# Chrome extension contextMenu popup

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to create a popup from a contextmenu?

Like this:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html

But, just from a ContextMenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `browserAction` popups can only be opened by a user clicking on a browserAction button.